# Surprised that $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{3} + 1$ has no extrema

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was doing a problem involving the first-derivative test for relative extrema for $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{3} + 1$ and found the derivative:
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{3} * x^\frac{-2}{3}$$

I then discovered that all my tools for finding roots (Quadratic formula, factoring, synthetic division) seem to not fit!
Obviously 0 is a root since there is only one term which is an x term. The answer in the back says "No relative extrema" which surprised me. How I might I have identified that there are no extrema?

Edit: changed on to one

Comment: $0$ is not a root of $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: "Obviously 0 is a root since there is only one term which is an x term".  There's your mistake.  $f'(x) = \frac 1{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$ which obviously does *not* have any roots.  And $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x} + 1$ of which it should not be surprising that it has no extrema.  It is monotonically increasing after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that to find extrema, set the derivative to zero and solve the equation:

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}} = 0$$
$$x^{-\frac{2}{3}} = 0$$
$$ \dfrac{1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}} = 0$$

Realize that no real number reciprocal will lead to $0$, thus the equation has no solution—meaning no local extrema.

Note that this doesn't necessarily mean there are no extrema. A good example is $f(x) = x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ which has a cusp at $0$, meaning it isn't differentiable there (and the equation of the derivative $\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}} = 0$ has no solutions), but the function still has an absolute minimum at $x = 0$. But in this case, $x^{\frac{1}{3}} + 1$ increases without bound in the positive and negative $y$ directions, thus there are also no absolute extrema.

$0$ is not a solution. $0^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ is undefined: $\dfrac{1}{0^{\frac{2}{3}}} = \dfrac{1}{0}$

Comment: A function can have no point where the derivative vanishes, but still have an absolute minimum (or maximum): consider $f(x)=|x|$. The trick is that the derivative doesn't exist at $0$, of course. But in your situation you *can't* claim there is no extremum just because the derivative vanishes nowhere.

Comment: @egreg That went right over my head. Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For fun:

Let $x\not =0$, $x$ real;

$y= x^{1/3} +1;$

$x \not=0$ implies $y \not =1.$

$(y-1)^3 =x;$

Differentiate both sides with resp. to $x$:

$3(y-1)^2\dfrac{dy}{dx} =1$, or

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{1}{3(y-1)^2}$, $y \not =1$.

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} >0$, $y \not=1$.

Hence for $x\not =0$,

$y=f(x) $ strictly increasing .

No maximum.

Answer (score 0):

note that $$\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}=\frac{1}{3x^{2/3}}\neq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful. It is true that if a function has an extremal point in the interior of its domain then the derivative vanishes at that point, ***provided the derivative exists at that point to begin with***.

A simple example is $g(x)=|x|$, which has obviously an absolute minimum at $0$, but its derivative vanishes nowhere (where it exists, of course).

Your function $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}+1$ has derivative
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}}
$$
which vanishes nowhere, *but does not exist at $0$*. This tells us that the function has no relative extremal points different from $0$, but tells us *nothing* about $0$.

On the other hand the derivative is everywhere positive on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$. Since the function is everywhere continuous, it is strictly increasing.

Hence the answer *no relative extremal point* is correct, but requires some more work than just using the fact that the derivative vanishes nowhere.

Beware also that if the function is defined, say, over $[a,b]$, then $a$ or $b$ *can* be extremal points even if the (one-sided) derivative doesn't vanish at those points. Think to $g(x)=x$ defined over $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

$0$ isn't a root of the derivative, it's a *pole*.

But that aside, $0$ really is a critical point of this function; the only one, in fact.

As a critical point, it's a place where a relative extremum *could* be located.

Not a place where one ***must*** be located.

That is your mistake; the fact $0$ is a critical point isn't a guarantee that it's actually a relative extrema; in fact, it's not.

The fact 0 is not a critical point can easily be seen from graphing the function:

[image: graph of the function] (source: [WolframAlpha)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sign(x)%20abs(x)%5E(1%2F3)%20%2B%201)

or even more simply by remembering that $x^{1/3}$ is a strictly increasing function of $x$. You don't even have to bother with computing derivatives to recognize that there are no relative extrema.